# How to use $in inside $or operator in MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the data as following documents...

```
[
  {
    "_id":"5e93193f755fc5e74beb5e8f",
    "orgs":[
      {
        "type":"NonEmployee",
        "roles":[]
      },
      {
        "type":"Founder",
        "roles":[
          {
            "_id":"5e44fd4546b3954e6930e83d",
            "name":"ADMIN"
          },
          {
            "_id":"5e44fd4546b3954e6930e83e",
            "name":"EMPLOYEE"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

The query which I am interested in is,
Filter Documents based on "OR" conditions of the following...

- If it has type as NonEmployee
- If it has role in given Array eg. rolesArray = ['EMPLOYEE']

The sub-query in aggregate looks something like this,

```
{
  $match: {
     $expr: {
      $or: [
        {
          $in: ["$orgs.roles.name", rolesArray]
        },
        {
          $eq: ['$orgs.type', 'NonEmployee']
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This gives result as an empty array, because query is incorrect. Is there any possible way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query it with **elematch** instead that matches all the specified query criteria.

You can refer to the doc: 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/

Answer (score 0):

> The query which I am interested in is, Filter Documents based on "OR"
>   conditions of the following...
>
> - If it has type as NonEmployee
> - If it has role in given Array eg.rolesArray = ['EMPLOYEE']

The aggregation query using `$match` stage and the operators `$or` and `$in`:

```
ROLES_ARRAY =  [ "EMPLOYEE", "OTHER" ]

db.collction.aggregate( [
  { 
      $match: { 
          $or: [ { "orgs.roles.name": { $in: ROLES_ARRAY  } }, { "orgs.type": "NonEmployee" } ] 
      } 
  }
] )
```

The same query using the `find` method:

```
db.collection.find( { $or: [ { "orgs.roles.name": { $in: ROLES_ARRAY  } }, { "orgs.type": "NonEmployee" } ] } )
```